# Flutter How to Save a Google Places Object Into Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-api

How can I achieve the following functionality:

**I'm attempting to save a `PlacesDetailsResponse`:**

```
prefs.setString("last_known_google_places_location", json.encode(_placeDetail));
```

**Then call it back like:**

```
PlacesDetailsResponse last_location_obj = json.decode(prefs.getString("last_known_google_places_location")!);
```

**Error:**

```
E/flutter ( 5976): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'PlacesDetailsResponse?'
E/flutter ( 5976): #0      MyWidget.example(package:flutter_listings/main.dart:381:17)
E/flutter ( 5976): <asynchronous suspension>
```

**I'm using the package:**

```
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
```

The code seems to suggest I can save it via json encode... here is the official class from the package:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class PlacesDetailsResponse extends GoogleResponseStatus {
  final PlaceDetails result;

  /// JSON html_attributions
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: <String>[])
  final List<String> htmlAttributions;

  PlacesDetailsResponse({
    required String status,
    String? errorMessage,
    required this.result,
    required this.htmlAttributions,
  }) : super(
          status: status,
          errorMessage: errorMessage,
        );

  factory PlacesDetailsResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PlacesDetailsResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PlacesDetailsResponseToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: how do you parse a PlacesDetailsResponse to JSON?

Comment: ` factory PlacesDetailsResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PlacesDetailsResponseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PlacesDetailsResponseToJson(this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was missing a step and not decoding the json into a `PlacesDetailsResponse` object, you can accomplish this via the class `fromJson` method:

```
 PlacesDetailsResponse the_last_place = PlacesDetailsResponse.fromJson(json.decode(prefs.getString("last_known_google_places_location")!));
```